# Passing long with an intent, always getting error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, long-integer

I need to pass a long (_id) with an intent from Activity A to Activity B, using this code:

```
Intent vip0= new Intent(this, PageSinglePlayerGuess.class);
vip0.putExtra("resid", (long) 1);
startActivity(vip0);
```

and getting it in Activity B with this method (called in onCreate()):

```
public long getResId() {
    Intent i= getIntent();
    resid= i.getLongExtra("resid", 1);
    Log.d("D", "Risorsa: " + resid);
    return resid;
}
```

resid in ActB is a long.
I get this error:

```
    06-06 11:10:47.138: W/Bundle(538): Key resid expected Long but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value 1 was returned.
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.os.Bundle.getLong(Bundle.java:966)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.content.Intent.getLongExtra(Intent.java:3874)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at com.gmail.corsalini.celebrityquiz.PageSinglePlayerGuess.getResId(PageSinglePlayerGuess.java:60)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at com.gmail.corsalini.celebrityquiz.PageSinglePlayerGuess.onCreate(PageSinglePlayerGuess.java:46)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-06 11:10:47.158: W/Bundle(538):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea how to solve this? (it seems really easy, but i just can't get out of it)

Comment: Have you tried: `vip0.putExtra("resid", 1L);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the log the problem seems to be in following:

`resid= i.getLongExtra("resid", 1);`

so change it to:

`resid= i.getLongExtra("resid", 1L);`

BTW: the getLongExtra implementation looks like this:

```
public long getLongExtra(String name, long defaultValue) {
   return mExtras == null ? defaultValue : mExtras.getLong(name, defaultValue);
}
```

So that's why see that it fails at line:

```
at android.os.Bundle.getLong(Bundle.java:966)
```

Comment: Perfect, it work. I tried with 1l (not capital L) and it didn't work!

Comment: Hm.. strange "l" should also work http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work anymore.'Intent vip0= new Intent(this, PageSinglePlayerGuess.class);
    vip0.putExtra("resid",  1L);
    startActivity(vip0);'
Same logcat as before!

Comment: Is the same as in the main question.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
vip0.putExtra("resid", 1L);
```

A long value is always declared with a `L` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Long.valueOf(Integer int) instead of (long) 1

This is because it is being seen as an int still.